# JavaFX 8 WebEngine: How to get console.log() from javascript to System.out in java?

Tags: webview, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I'm using both JavaFX and the javascript engine inside JavaFX WebEngine to develop an application. I'd like to get feedback from javascript for debugging purposes. What happens to the console output inside the WebEngine? Is there any way I can access it, or redirect to System.out in java?

Answer (score 27):

The following code redirects `console.log()` to `JavaBridge.log()`:

```
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

[...]

public class JavaBridge
{
    public void log(String text)
    {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}

// Maintain a strong reference to prevent garbage collection:
// https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154127
private final JavaBridge bridge = new JavaBridge();

[...]

webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
{
    JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
    window.setMember("java", bridge);
    webEngine.executeScript("console.log = function(message)\n" +
        "{\n" +
        "    java.log(message);\n" +
        "};");
});
```

Comment: what is "window" here?

Comment: @Florian can you please help here? I'm getting a null pointer exception if i declare window as JSObject

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj you need to post a separate question.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. My calls to `console.log()` isn't being picked up for some reason.

Comment: Not sure if we need to do this every time state changes - perhaps just when `newValue == State.SCHEDULED` or something? otherwise we are overriding `console.log` multiple times for no reason, in the same request.

Comment: If this silently fails for you like it did for me, one thing to try is initializing `bridge` in a persistent scope (e.g., as an member variable of an object, instead of a local variable). I think my bridge was garbage collected before it could be called from JavaScript (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903154 for details about `setMember` and garbage collection)

Comment: @AndrewHead I fixed the answer. Thank you for pointing his out!

Comment: @SleepyFox89 State.SCHEDULED doesn't work for me, it fails when I load a second page in the same WebView. However, State.SUCCEEDED works.

Comment: I was stumped since `import netscape.javascript.JSObject;` is deprecated in Java 9 and `import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;` is deprecated in Java 15, with no replacements mentioned anywhere - I am using Java 20. Finally discovered that if you add `requires jdk.jsobject;` to your `src/main/java/module-info.java` then you can access `import netscape.javascript.JSObject;`. Not sure if this is kosher but it works.

Answer (score 13):

You can just add message listener to see what's happening in your output. You don't have to inject js bridge with redefinition of functions like `console.log` for every single loaded page

```
WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener((webView, message, lineNumber, sourceId) -> {
    System.out.println(message + "[at " + lineNumber + "]");
});
```

Comment: Yes, but you don't get the ability to expand and view the arguments passed to console methods or jump to source like you get from the debugger console.

Comment: He just asked about getting output from console.log, so it's better alternative to Green Man's answer. Dedicated debugging tools belong to another case and it is not always helping - for example if we want to catch output in our final distributed app.

Comment: Sadly WebConsoleListener is not available in recent versions of Java.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. package com.sun.javafx.webkit; but it is not event from java, I'm using the lastest javaFX version, it is here

Comment: Avoid! It uses internal API which might be removed in any release.

Comment: As the comments predicted.... sadly... this stopped working in newer FX versions :(

Answer (score 6):

I like to go the other direction.  We use log4j so I created a javascript wrapper like the following:

```
module.exports = {

    levels:[ "ALL", "TRACE", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "OFF"],

    level:"INFO",

    error:function(msg){
      if(this.isErrorEnabled()){
        console.error(msg)
      }
    },
    warn:function(msg){
      if(this.isWarnEnabled()){
        console.warn(msg)
      }
    },
    info:function(msg){
      if(this.isInfoEnabled()){
        console.log("INFO: "+msg)
      }
    },
    debug:function(msg){
      if(this.isDebugEnabled()){
        console.log("DEBUG: "+msg)
      }
    },
    trace:function(msg){
      if(this.isTraceEnabled()){
        console.log("TRACE: "+msg)
      }
    },

    isErrorEnabled:function(){
      return this.isEnabled("ERROR");
    },
    isWarnEnabled:function(){
      return this.isEnabled("WARN");
    },
    isInfoEnabled:function(){
      return this.isEnabled("INFO");
    },
    isDebugEnabled:function(){
      return this.isEnabled("DEBUG");
    },
    isTraceEnabled:function(){
      return this.isEnabled("TRACE");
    },
    isEnabled:function(statementLevel){
      return this.levels.indexOf(this.level)<=this.levels.indexOf(statementLevel);
    }
  }
```

Then at the beginning of the javascript I check to see if the log is present and set it:

```
if(window.log == undefined){
  window.log = require("./utils/log4j-wrapper")
  window.log.level = "INFO"
}
```

And that way if you set the Log4j logger directly on the engine before you even load the url like:

```
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine()
JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window")
win.setMember("log", log)  //log being the java log4j logger
```

This way I can get logging in if I am opening directly in a browser or it is being run from a WebView in a JavaFX program.  And has the added benefit of having levels to the logging in javascript that match your packages of the WebView controller.  Just an alternative for larger javascript views.