# How to debug JavaScript in the WebView of JavaFx?

Tags: javascript, debugging, javafx, javafx-2, firebug

I am developing **JavaFx** application with **WebView** loaded some HTML and **Java** **Script**.

I have tried **FireBug** **Lite** for debug purpose, but its not letting to debug the JavaScript.

Is there any way to debug the javascaript that is loaded into the **WebView** of JavaFX?

Comment: Do you want just the logging output ? You can try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687640/javafx-8-webengine-how-to-get-console-log-from-javascript-to-system-out-in-ja

Comment: The mentioned FireBug Lite was helpful but does not seem to work any more, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521474/how-to-include-firebug-light-without-access-to-http-getfirebug-com

Answer (score 0):

I did not try them but those projects might be of help:

https://gitlab.com/mohamnag/javafx-webview-debugger

https://github.com/vsch/Javafx-WebView-Debugger

Related old question:

[Html/Javascript debugging in JavaFX WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398879/html-javascript-debugging-in-javafx-webview/34444807#34444807)