# How to include firebug light without access to http://getfirebug.com?

Tags: javascript, debugging, webview, firebug-lite

In the past I could include firebug light as described here:

[Html/Javascript debugging in JavaFX WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398879/html-javascript-debugging-in-javafx-webview)

Unfortunately, the link

http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js

is currently broken.

I found the source code for firebug light at https://github.com/firebug/firebug-lite

However, I did not manage to include it from there or clone the repo and use it offline.

I also failed to include firebug-light.min.js from

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebug-lite/1.4.0/firebug-lite.min.js

=> How can i include firebug light without access to http://getfirebug.com?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I stopped using JavaFx.

Comment: Maybe the archive.org versions of the second link are embeddable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the same problem debugging an old embedded IE in an eclipse RCP app I searched my old disk archives and found the original sources.

A slighty adapted version of firebug-lite v1.2 can now be found here: https://lupatec.eu/getfirebug , visit the link for instructions or simply replace the original firebug url http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js by https://lupatec.eu/getfirebug/firebug-lite-compressed.js

Comment: The site appears to be offline now?

Comment: It's back online.

Comment: It is offline again, unfortunately

Comment: You can get it on `web.archive.org`.
The one on `https://lupatec.eu/` seems to be slightly different and not work perfectly.
https://web.archive.org/web/20130320104451/https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js